# How to detect if a doc document password protected

Tags: c#, office-interop

I have a folder with lots of doc-documents and I need to upload their context into database. The problem is that some of them are password protected and I don't know the password. I would like to skip them but I don't know how to detect if password protection presents.

P.S. Programming language is C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These links seem to answer your question:
[To know Word is password protected](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/991af08f-d80e-4604-828d-d54dde8fc7bf)
[Skipping Password-Protected Documents in a Batch Process](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/CheckIfPWProtectB4Open.htm)